# Logs of multiple servers in hawtio dashboard

Tags: apache-camel, hawtio

I've a hawtio 1.4.45 running in Jetty Server A where my camel application is also deployed. There is another camel application and jolokia web agent running on Jetty Server B. I'm able to get basic camel MBean details from both Server A and Server B. However I get to see the logs of only Server A and NOT Server B's. Is there any JMX settings to bring up the logs of Server B to hawtio Dashboard?

Comment: Is server A and server B different what they have installed? And you need insight-log for the log plugin to be able to read and show logs

Comment: Thanks Claus Ibesn for your quick response. Server A and Server B are two different jetty bases having different camel applications deployed. Let me try with with insight-log plugin and update you.

Comment: Let us know if you get any luck with this

Comment: I'm right now concentrating setting up in one server, where I'm hitting road blocks.. Will let you know by end of this week about this.

Comment: I'm able to see logs tab after adding insight-log4j and loading logQuery as part of applicationContext.xml. However, camel events are not appearing in logs tab. This could be of help to me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27832931/jetty-how-to-make-a-camel-application-log-events-to-the-hawtio-logs-tab