# Mulitple camel applications logging to single hawtio

Tags: tomcat, apache-camel, hawtio

I've configured our Camel applications to log to Hawtio using the following:

pom.xml

```
  <dependency>
        <groupId>io.fabric8.insight</groupId>
        <artifactId>insight-log4j</artifactId>  
        <version>${insight-log4j}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j-version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

And camelContext.xml

```
    <bean id="logQuery" class="io.fabric8.insight.log.log4j.Log4jLogQuery" lazy-init="false" scope="singleton"
    init-method="start" destroy-method="stop"/>
```

The camel webapps work fine individually but when they are on the same Tomcat v8 only the last installed Camel app logs are displayed in Hawtio. [All camel apps are displayed in the camel tab].

Comment: Possibly the same issue as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28238101/logs-of-multiple-servers-in-hawtio-dashboard